# How does mapcat work?

Tags: function, vector, clojure

I am really new to clojure! How does `mapcat work?

Comment: if you are really new to clojure (or any programming language) it's a really good idea to read some tutorial or a book before asking on SO.

Answer (score 8):

[`mapcat` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat) is just a shortcut for applying [`concat` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/concat) to the result of [`map` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map):

```clj
=> (mapcat reverse [[3 2 1 0] [6 5 4] [9 8 7]])
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

=> (apply concat (map reverse [[3 2 1 0] [6 5 4] [9 8 7]]))
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

### References:

- [official Clojure API docs](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/mapcat)
- [clojuredocs.org website](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat)

---

By using `mapcat` in combination with [`vector` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vector/) you can interlace several collections:

```
=> (mapcat vector [1 2 3 4 5 6] [:q :w :e :r :t :y])
(1 :q 2 :w 3 :e 4 :r 5 :t 6 :y)
```

You'll get the same result using [`list` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/list/) instead of `vector`.